# Can't figure it out? Keep chipping away!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

My beginning (sort of) describes the way I'm created,
The importance of my ending can't be understated.
Before I am finished, I'm nothing but money,
Though throughout the whole process, I'm sweeter than honey.
I'm used by a spider that looks for his house,
And strange things can happen when I'm received by a mouse.
Be branded a monster if you love me too dear,
But not a monster that many have reason to fear.

What am I?

HINT:

> My beginning and my ending might overlap

Comment: This is a super fun puzzle!  Thank you for creating and sharing it!  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you a:

> Cookie?

My beginning (sort of) describes the way I'm created,

> Cook (well, bake)

The importance of my ending can't be understated.

> Without the "ie" ending you'd be left with a "cook," which is quite a different thing...

Before I am finished, I'm nothing but money,

> Before it's a cookie, it's dough (and dough is a slang term for money).

Though throughout the whole process, I'm sweeter than honey.

> Cookies are deliciously sweet - as dough or as the finished product!

I'm used by a spider that looks for his house,

> Perhaps this one is a bit of a stretch, but: [web spiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) (also known as web crawlers) sometimes use cookies (the internet kind!)

And strange things can happen when I'm received by a mouse.

> Referring, I assume, to the children's book [If You Give a Mouse a Cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_You_Give_a_Mouse_a_Cookie).

Be branded a monster if you love me too dear,
But not a monster that many have reason to fear.

> Cookie Monster - a monster indeed, but not a scary one!

And the title:

> I assume refers to a chocolate *chip* cookie!

Comment: Very impressive how you come up with this so quickly.

Comment: That was incredibly fast! Nice work! I'll give you some time to work out the last few clues, but I'll give you the checkmark once you've got them worked out (PS: You're correct that you're going in the wrong direction on the spider clue)

Comment: It was the title that tipped me off, as well as the "sweeter than honey" bit - plus of course, the later it gets, the more my thoughts stray towards dessert ;-)  I'll keep working on those last ones!

Comment: You still aren't quite there on those last 2 hints. However, I talked with some people in real life, and they agreed that those clues aren't structured as well as I had hoped, so I'm going to mark this answer correct now.  I'm also going to add some hints for the last 2 clues, if you want to keep plugging away at them. At any rate, excellent work :D

Comment: Actually, you're close enough on the spider line. You got the gist of what I was looking for, though I had a specific phrase in mind

Comment: Still stuck on that "ending" line - all I can think of is kooky, which doesn't seem related - and I'm curious what you were thinking of for the "spider" line, @Belgabad?

Comment: @puzzledPig  
>! For the "ending" line, something that's very important could be described as "key" (again, based on feedback I agree this was a stretch at best). For the spider line, I was looking for "web browser", as a description of "a spider who looks for his house"

Comment: @Belgabad ah, once I've heard that, it makes perfect sense (per usual)... :)  thanks for the great puzzle!

Comment: Happy you enjoyed it :)